# How to bypass CSP(Content-Security-Policy) using puppeteer's API page.addScriptTag?

Tags: google-chrome, headless, puppeteer

scenario:

I use puppeteer launched chrome in headless mode, and call `page.addScriptTag` with an cross-domain javascript file. Now if the opening site has csp set and restricts only same origin javascript tags, how can I bypass this using puppeteer API?

Answer (score 21):

Use:

```
await page.setBypassCSP(true)
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetbypasscspenabled)

Answer (score 7):

This is my first stackoverflow contribution so have mercy on me. I found this work around to allow you to get past CSP, [Here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1229).

The basic idea is that you intercept page requests and use a library like node-fetch to make the request and disable the CSP header when passing it back to chrome.

Here's the snippet that initially came from the github issue tracker.

Replace "example.com" with the website that needs to have CSP disabled.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const requestInterceptor = async (request) => {
  try {
    const url = request.url()
    const requestHeaders = request.headers()
    const acceptHeader = requestHeaders.accept || ''
    if (url.includes("example.com") && (acceptHeader.includes('text/html'))) {
      const cookiesList = await page.cookies(url)
      const cookies = cookiesList.map(cookie => `${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}`).join('; ')
      delete requestHeaders['x-devtools-emulate-network-conditions-client-id']
      if (requestHeaders.Cookie) {
        requestHeaders.cookie = requestHeaders.Cookie
        delete requestHeaders.Cookie
      }
      const theseHeaders = Object.assign({'cookie': cookies}, requestHeaders, {'accept-language': 'en-US,en'})

      const init = {
        body: request.postData(),
        headers: theseHeaders,
        method: request.method(),
        follow: 20,
      }
      const result = await fetch(
        url,
        init,
      )
      const resultHeaders = {}
      result.headers.forEach((value, name) => {
        if (name.toLowerCase() !== 'content-security-policy') {
          resultHeaders[name] = value
        } else {
          console.log('CSP', `omitting CSP`, {originalCSP: value})
        }
      })
      const buffer = await result.buffer()
      await request.respond({
        body: buffer,
        resultHeaders,
        status: result.status,
      })
    } else {
      request.continue();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error while disabling CSP", e);
    request.abort();
  }
}

await page.setRequestInterception(true)
page.on('request', requestInterceptor)
```